# Randomize path in JMeter REST API load testing

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

So I have a REST API that I want to test with JMeter.
I have few different paths in the REST Service.

If we take an example of simple REST service that will calculate based on two values passed in request, I have four different paths 
`/add`
`/sub`
`/mul`
`/div`

Now I want to test this with a 5000 requests but want to randomize the path and the values in request parameters in each request. Also if possible, want to get the results in 4 categories separately for each path.

Can someone please suggest the right combination of elements?
I am very new to JMeter and hence, expect a little elaborated answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest and the easiest way is using [__chooseRandom()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#chooseRandomsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-0-1-font-sup) function available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/). The relevant configuration of the HTTP Request Sampler would be:

- Path: `/${__chooseRandom(add,sub,mul,div,path)}` - get a random option and store it into `${path}` JMeter Variable
- Name: `${path}` - change [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Label (for separate reporting)

[image: ChooseRandom]

You can install __chooseRandom() and other plugins Functions via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) from the "Available Plugins" tab:

[image: Custom Functions Plugins manager]

---

Be aware that your requests will be **random** hence your test scenario won't be repeatable so I would recommend considering using other test elements instead i.e. [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) or [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) or [Weighted Switch Controller](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WeightedSwitchController/).

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for above test elements configuration details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri. This is a very elaborated answer. Exactly something I was looking for. I'll check if I can make this work and get back if I run into walls.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri. The solution worked exactly as intended.